# GTEST : Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL

Tags: unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I am learning GMock in gtest. I have a below scenario

```
class Observer 
{
public:
   virtual void StartObserver(const std::string&, const int&) { }
};

class MockObserver : public Observer
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD2(StartObserver, void(const std::string &, const int &));
};

class Worker
{
private :
    std::shared_ptr<observer> mObserver = nullptr;
public :
    void StartObserver(const std::string& str, const int& val)
    {
        mObserver->StartObserver(str, val);
    }
    void RegisterObserver(std::shared_ptr<Observer> observer)
    {
        mObserver = observer;
    }
};
```

In my Test function I did the testing like below

```
TEST_(AppTest, Test_Observer)
{
    Worker w;
    std::shared_ptr<MockObserver> mockObserver = std::make_shared<MockObserver>();
    
    w.RegisterObserver(mockObserver); //instead of actual ObserverObject I passed mockObserver here 
    EXPECT_CALL (*mockObserver, StartObserver(_, _)).Times(1).WillOnce(::testing::Return());;
    w.StartObserver("hello", 100);
}
```

While running gTest I am getting below error on this test

```
Actual function call count doesn't match EXPECT_CALL(*mockObserver, StartObserver(_, _))...
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

Is there anything wrong with my code ?

Comment: Can't reproduce your issue. Which version of gtest are you using?

Comment: @jdfa I am not sure what exact version it is. But I see something like this in README.version file     URL: https://github.com/google/googletest
Version: ff07a5de0e81580547f1685e101194ed1a4fcd56